# Symmetrizing a row stochastic matrix by left multiplication of positive diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $D$ be a row stochastic matrix, i.e. a real square matrix with the properties:

- $d_{ij} \in [0,1]$,
- $\sum_j d_{ij} = 1$.

Let $x$ be a positive vector. I need to find a row stochastic matrix $P$ such that $\operatorname{diag}(x)P$ is symmetric.

Is it possible to take $P = AD$ for some square matrix $A$? If so, how could I obtain $A$ so that $\operatorname{diag}(x)AD$ is symmetric?

Comment: What do $xIP$ and $xI(AD)$ mean?  Why aren't they $xP$ and $xAD$, repectively? Do you mean $xI$ to denote  a diagonal matrix whose diagonal terms are the entries in $x$?

Comment: Yes, I mean "$x I$" to be the diagonal matrix with entries $x$. Is $x I P$ the same as $x P$?

Comment: No, $xI$ without extra info means matrix multiplication and equals to $x$.

Comment: If $D$ is nonsingular, you may take $A=D^{-1}$ and $P=AD=I$.

Answer (score 0):

No. Suppose $D=\pmatrix{1/2&1/4&1/4\\1/4&1/4&1/2\\1/2&1/4&1/4}$. You want $x,y,z$ so that $$\pmatrix{x&0&0\\0&y&0\\0&0&z}\pmatrix{1/2&1/4&1/4\\1/4&1/4&1/2\\1/2&1/4&1/4}= \pmatrix{x/2&x/4&x/4\\y/4&y/4&y/2\\z/2&z/4&z/4}$$ is symmetric, so that $$x/4=y/4, x/4=z/2, y/2=z/4$$ that is, so that $$x=y, x=2z, z=2y.$$  This can happen only if $x=y=z=0$, which of course are not positive.